# "No such index at level 1" error in assigning row names

Tags: r

I am a beginner with R and keep running into this issue. I need help in understanding what exactly is wrong and what would be the correct way to code it.

```
R <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
C <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
rownames(a) <- R
colnames(a) <- C
a <- read.table("/Users/apple/Desktop/R/datasample.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "", quote = "\"'", dec = ".", as.is = FALSE, na.strings = "NA", colClasses = NA, nrows = 8, skip = 0, check.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE, strip.white = FALSE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE, comment.char = "#", match.arg(rownames(a), several.ok = TRUE), rownames(a) <- R)
```

> Error in formal.args[[as.character(substitute(arg))]] : 
>         no such index at level 1

Comment: Why is `rownames(a) <- R` inside `read.table()`??

Comment: You should read `a` before setting row and col names. Please, provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you. Once it is outside the read.table() function it works perfectly. Thank you all very much